# Connect to a LOKI remote node when using the CLI wallet

Tags: monero-forks, wallet, loki, cli

What is the command to connect to a LOKI remote node if I do not want to download the entire LOKI blockchain? I am using the ubuntu cli wallet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following format:

```
./loki-wallet-cli --daemon-host imaginary.stream
```